# Cannot find "TouchRespondScrollView"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I´m trying to port a swift iOS controller to Xamarin iOS.

In swift

```
let _mainScrollView = TouchRespondScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
_mainScrollView.delegate = self
_mainScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

self.mainScrollView  = _mainScrollView

self.view.addSubview(_mainScrollView)
```

Is this correct in C#

```
var mainScroll = new UIScrollView(this.View.Bounds);
mainScroll.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
mainScroll.Delegate = new ProfileViewDelegate();
this.mainscrollView = mainScroll;

this.View.AddSubview(mainScroll);
```

Couldn't find any information about "TouchRespondScrollView" in Xamarin docs.

Comment: this is not a standard control - it's probably a custom class in the code that you're trying to port

Comment: Thanks you where right it was an internal class.